# get day from date in php

Tags: php

I have the code below which I got from the php: mktime manual just edited it to use my own variables but for the day I always get "1".

```
$requested_day = $_GET['day'];
$requested_month = $_GET['month'];
$requested_year = $_GET['year'];

if (!empty ($requested_day) || empty ($requested_month) || empty ($requested_year))
{
    echo $requested_day. " ".$requested_month." ".$requested_year." is on day : ". date("1", mktime(0, 0, 0, $requested_month, $requested_day, $requested_year));


}
```

I enter the values and it is outputted as:

```
23 09 2010 is on day : 1
```

I think I am having a problem on the "1" I entered on the date, I don't quite understand what this is actually for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string should have a lower case L not a number one.

```
date("l", mktime(...
```

The "l" in the format string says to show the day of the week.

Comment: @Elliott, don't feel that. Sometimes we all need a second set of eyes.

Comment: I know the feeling, Elliott. I've felt it countless times and will continue to do so from time to time as long as I'm trying to learn new things. Which I hope I will never quit doing!

Answer (score 2):

Brace yourself:

1 != l (the latter is a lower-case L)